# Decoding data from serial port (string with integers)

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, serial-port, string-decoding

I'm sending string from Arduino to PC using serial communication. Format of message includes char, value and space (separating data). Example message: `"H123 V2 L63 V2413 I23 CRC2a"`. 
I have problem with decoding this message in Qt because when I use for example Utf-8 decoding it casting integers to chars (in a simplified way) and I receiving something like that: `"H&?? j\u0002I&\u001AICL?H"`. Message length is not constant (different size for ex. `H12` and `H123`) so I can't use predetermined position to casting. Do you have any idea how to decode message correctly?

Arduino code:

```cpp
uint8_t H = 0, V = 0, L = 0, I = 0, CRC = 0;
String data;
void loop() {
  ++H; ++V; ++L; ++I;
  data = String("H");
  data += String(H, DEC);
  data += String(" V");
  data += String(V, DEC);
  data += String(" L");
  data += String(L, DEC);
  data += String(" I");
  data += String(I, DEC);
  CRC = CRC8(data.c_str(), strlen(data.c_str()));
  data += String(" CRC");
  data += String(CRC, HEX);
  Serial.println(data);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Qt code:

```cpp
while(serial.isOpen())
{
  QByteArray data;

  if (serial.waitForReadyRead(1000))
  {
    data = serial.readLine();
    while (serial.waitForReadyRead(100))
    {
        data += serial.readAll();
    }
    QString response = QString::fromUtf8(data);
    qDebug() << "Data " << response << endl;
  }
  else
    qDebug() << "Timeout";
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need utf-8 here? Use for example `QString::fromAscii(data.data())`

Comment: There's not method called 
`QString::fromAscii()`. QString Class documentation: 
[link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)

Comment: Baud rate ? Same on both sides ?  Which Arduino? String::operator+ is one of the most difficult operations on an avr Arduino. ( And completey unnecessary here)

Comment: Ok solved I've set in Qt Even Parity but default for Arduino is No Parity. Second thing encoding should be `QString::fromLocal8Bit(data)`. What is strange for `Serial.println("Test")` it worked correctly. Thank you datafiddler and Michael O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use UTF-8 decoding, while Arduino send just 1-byte ASCII chars. So use `fromLocal8Bit` as said albert828

Like this:

```
while(serial.isOpen())
{
  QByteArray data;

  if (serial.waitForReadyRead(1000))
  {
    data = serial.readLine();
    while (serial.waitForReadyRead(100))
    {
        data += serial.readAll();
    }
    QString response = QString::fromLocal8Bit(data);
    qDebug() << "Data " << response << endl;
  }
  else
    qDebug() << "Timeout";
}
```